# Inconsistent Tagging Scheme

Tags: discussion, tagging

It appears that there is somewhat of an inconsistent tagging scheme for the Adobe suite programs:

- adobe-illustrator
- photoshop

Comment: I agree, but it's also true that "photoshop" really needs no clarification. There is no other photoshop to refer to. Illustrator, on the other hand, could refer either to the program or to the profession, so it needs to clarification of "adobe-illustrator"

Comment: Would be really inconsistent though... Wouldn't Adobe-Photoshop be better than Photoshop? ... After all, Photoshop could mean 'Photoshopped images' or something... And to extend this idea, ... What about Adobe Fireworks? Would 'Fireworks' be adequate? And 'Flash' too?

Comment: As of the time I have written this, all photoshop tags have been changed to adobe-photoshop. I think you can just make a synonym for both of them no ? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/photoshop/synonyms

Answer (score 9):

I'm all for taking a note from SO and using the more complete tag.  After all, if you start typing in "photo" and "adobe-photoshop" is in the system, it'll come up as an option.